# Running a CentOS Docker Image on Arch Linux exits with code 139?

Tags: centos, arch-linux, docker

I am trying to run a CentOS Docker Image on my Arch Linux host.  Running the following command returns nothing except the 139 error code:

```
$ docker run -ti centos:centos6 /bin/bash                                                                                                                                
[139] $
```

I have the CentOS Docker image:

```
centos              centos6             0cbf37812bff        2 weeks ago         194MB
```

and a centOS container is there under the list of containers

```
$ docker ps -a|grep cento                                                                                                                                                
2ef0f0d7439c        centos:centos6         "/bin/bash"              5 minutes ago       Exited (139) 5 minutes ago                       elated_turing
```

Docker logs also returns nothing:

```
$ docker logs <container id>
$
```

I have tried using other Docker images and they work, it only seems to affect the CentOS image but I need to use centOS for my work.

Comment: What does `docker logs <container>` show?

Comment: @slm nothing is returned

Comment: Can you try removing the container and then removing the image and re-downloading it again?

Comment: Also make sure SELinux is enabled - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1488516.

Comment: @slm SELinux isn't fully supported with Arch, and the installation process includes about 100 steps, so are you sure this will solve it? 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SELinux#Current_status_in_Arch_Linux

Comment: Nope, just giving leads.

Answer (score 9):

They were changes made on vsyscall linking in the Linux Kernel, starting with version 4.11, that caused issues with containers running Centos 6.x

2 solutions :

- Use a 7.x Centos image
- Try to boot the kernel with the parameter `vsyscall=emulate`

*Example with GRUB*, modify `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vsyscall=emulate"
```

And then run `update-grub`

*Example with systemd-boot*, modify your conf in `/boot/loader/entries` and add the parameter to the options line :

```
title Arch Linux
linux /vmlinuz-linux
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
options *EXISTINGPARAMS* vsyscall=emulate
```

Comment: damn! that was the issue... don't know how you figured this out, but thanks a bunch, you save my day (and probably a large fraction of my night!)

Comment: Related docs on how to add Kernel parameters: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB
and `sudo update-grub` worked for me on Manjaro

Comment: Do you have any references to the underlying issue?

Comment: The vsyscall  parameter was set to 'none' by default in 4.11, and I think the problem is with the version of glibc in Centos 6 which does not support this. You could search the kernel mailing list for the exact patch were this happened.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `vsyscall=emulate` as advised in the other answer, of course, but if you can't reboot the machine containing CentOS 6 container (or just a CentOS 6 installation inside a chroot, as in my case) and don't mind some open-heart surgery, you can also "upgrade" CentOS 6 to use CentOS 7 glibc version to work around the problem. Note that replacing just `libc.so` is not enough, you need to copy at least the following files from a CentOS 7 system to `/lib64` directory: `ld-2.17.so`, `lib{c,dl,m,pthread}-2.17.so` and then update the corresponding symlinks, i.e. `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, `libc.so.6`, `libdl.so.2`, `libm.so.6` and `libpthread.so.0` to point to 2.17 versions instead of 2.12 ones.